# How to use Nokogiri to make many changes to an XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to convert a pretty big XML file, over 80K rows, to a CSV format.

I need to mass edit the `<ImageFile />` node to  something like

```
www.mybaseurl.com + text of <ImageFile />
```

That way it could have the full image path. I looked at all their documentation and Stack Overflow and, while straightforward, I still can't find a solution for my problem.

I want to use Ruby to check if `<AltImageFile1>` is empty and if it isn’t I need the to create a new row right below with the same handle value but the value of

```
<AltImageFile1> for <ImageFile />
```

like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eENoE.png)

Here is a sample of the file XML I am working with:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>36-In. Homeowner Bent Single-Bit Axe Handle</Name>
    <Description>This single bit curved grip axe handle is made for 3 to 5 pound axes. A good quality replacement handle made of American hickory with a natural wax finish. Hardwood handles do not conduct electricity and American Hickory is known for its strength, elasticity and ability to absorb shock. These handles provide exceptional value and economy for homeowners and other occasional use applications. Each Link handle comes with the required wedges, rivets, or epoxy needed for proper application of the tool head.</Description>
    <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>103387-1.jpg</AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>

  <Product>
    <Name>1-1/4-Inch Lavatory Pop Up Assembly</Name>
    <Description>Classic chrome finish with ABS plastic top &amp; body includes push rod, no overflow.</Description>
    <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>103429-1.jpg</AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>

  <Product>
    <Name>30-Inch Belt-Drive Whole-House Attic Fan With Shutter</Name>
    <Description>The 30" belt drive whole house fan (5700 CFM) with automatic shutter helps cool living spaces up to 1900 square feet. It runs on high &amp; low and a 2 speed wall switch is included. The automatic shutter is white. It needs 1095 square inches of open exhaust vents in attic space, with a rough opening of 34-1/4" x 29". You do have to cut joist when installing fan, with the motor mounted on struts above housing. The fan will be quieter than direct drive models. There is a 10 year limited parts warranty, 5 year limited labor warranty.</Description>

    <ImageFile>100073.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Here is my code. How can I improve this?

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = File.read('Desktop/roduct_catalog.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

all_the_things = []

doc.xpath('//Products/Product').each do |file|
  handle = file.xpath("./ItemNumber").first.text 
  title          = file.xpath("./Name").first.text
  description       = file.xpath("./Description").first.text
  collection = file.xpath("./FLDeptName").first.text 
  image1 = file.xpath("./ImageFile").first.text 
  all_the_things << [ handle, title, description, collection, image1]
end


CSV.open('product_file_1.csv', 'wb' ) do |row|
  row << [ 'handle', 'title', 'description', 'collection', 'image1']
  all_the_things.each do |data|
    row << data
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't select answers immediately. It takes 24 hours for the earth to turn, and often a week for all members to weigh in with solutions. Selecting an answer discourages further solutions, and you might find better, more flexible, more succinct answers by waiting.

Comment: Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need your minimal code that demonstrates the problem, the minimal input and the required output _in the question itself_. You did pretty good with the first two, but your output can't be an image, provide it as text.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am new on here and want to be as helpful as possible to the community. I didn't have a better way of displaying the issue. i will work on it. @theTinMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>36-In. Homeowner Bent Single-Bit Axe Handle</Name>
    <Description>This single bit curved grip axe handle is made for 3 to 5 pound axes. A good quality replacement handle made of American hickory with a natural wax finish. Hardwood handles do not conduct electricity and American Hickory is known for its strength, elasticity and ability to absorb shock. These handles provide exceptional value and economy for homeowners and other occasional use applications. Each Link handle comes with the required wedges, rivets, or epoxy needed for proper application of the tool head.</Description>
    <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>103387-1.jpg</AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>

  <Product>
    <Name>1-1/4-Inch Lavatory Pop Up Assembly</Name>
    <Description>Classic chrome finish with ABS plastic top &amp; body includes push rod, no overflow.</Description>
    <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>103429-1.jpg</AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>

  <Product>
    <Name>30-Inch Belt-Drive Whole-House Attic Fan With Shutter</Name>
    <Description>The 30" belt drive whole house fan (5700 CFM) with automatic shutter helps cool living spaces up to 1900 square feet. It runs on high &amp; low and a 2 speed wall switch is included. The automatic shutter is white. It needs 1095 square inches of open exhaust vents in attic space, with a rough opening of 34-1/4" x 29". You do have to cut joist when installing fan, with the motor mounted on struts above housing. The fan will be quieter than direct drive models. There is a 10 year limited parts warranty, 5 year limited labor warranty.</Description>

    <ImageFile>100073.jpg</ImageFile>
    <AltImageFile1>
    <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
    <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
  </Product>
</Products>
EOT
```

This is the logic:

```
NODES_TO_COLUMNS = {
  'ItemNumber'  => 'handle',
  'Name'        => 'title',
  'Description' => 'description',
  # 'FLDeptName'  => 'collection',
  'ImageFile'   => 'image1'
}

all_things = doc.search('Product').map do |product|
  NODES_TO_COLUMNS.keys.map { |node|
    product.at(node).text
  }
end

CSV.open('/dev/stdout', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << NODES_TO_COLUMNS.values
  all_things.each do |r|
    csv << r
  end
end
```

Which, when run, results in:

```
handle,title,description,image1
100024,36-In. Homeowner Bent Single-Bit Axe Handle,"This single bit curved grip axe handle is made for 3 to 5 pound axes. A good quality replacement handle made of American hickory with a natural wax finish. Hardwood handles do not conduct electricity and American Hickory is known for its strength, elasticity and ability to absorb shock. These handles provide exceptional value and economy for homeowners and other occasional use applications. Each Link handle comes with the required wedges, rivets, or epoxy needed for proper application of the tool head.",100024.jpg
100024,1-1/4-Inch Lavatory Pop Up Assembly,"Classic chrome finish with ABS plastic top & body includes push rod, no overflow.",100024.jpg
100024,30-Inch Belt-Drive Whole-House Attic Fan With Shutter,"The 30"" belt drive whole house fan (5700 CFM) with automatic shutter helps cool living spaces up to 1900 square feet. It runs on high & low and a 2 speed wall switch is included. The automatic shutter is white. It needs 1095 square inches of open exhaust vents in attic space, with a rough opening of 34-1/4"" x 29"". You do have to cut joist when installing fan, with the motor mounted on struts above housing. The fan will be quieter than direct drive models. There is a 10 year limited parts warranty, 5 year limited labor warranty.",100073.jpg
```

Because `FLDeptName` is missing in the XML, which it *should not be* to be a proper question on SO, I commented it out. How to use it is left for you.

You'll want to change:

```
CSV.open('/dev/stdout', 'wb') do |csv|
```

to whatever you want to use for the filename. `'/dev/stdout'` is merely an way for me to preserve the coding and route output to STDOUT to display it.

In your code you're using things like:

```
xpath("./ItemNumber").first.text
```

Don't do that. Nokogiri provides the `at` shortcut which is equivalent to `xpath....first` but is more succinct. Also, it's not necessary to use `xpath` as Nokogiri's `search` and `at` methods are smart enough to figure out what is an XPath or CSS selector almost every time.

I'd also recommend not using XPath unless forced to. CSS selectors are more readable and include many jQuery CSS extensions (if not all by now) so you can avoid some XPath visual noise using them.

Your requirement to create a secondary, mostly-blank row if `AltImageFile1` is not empty isn't something I'd do or recommend. A CSV row is considered a single, separate, record, and would be interpreted as that by every application that supports CSV I've seen, so you're asking to create a secondary record without fields that is a non-standard format. Instead, that field should be appended to the same row as an additional field. That logic isn't hard and is left for you to figure out.

The [IETF CSV document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) specifies:

> Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
> break (CRLF).  For example:

```
   aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
   zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
```

As a result, *not* doing that will break data movement through a lot of other applications, which is something you should want to avoid as CSV is supposed to be for data transfer.

If you are moving the data into a DBM, create a temporary table for importing directly from the XML, perform database statements to manipulate the records appropriately and then append them to the primary table. If you are importing the data into Excel, use a separate table, modify the fields, then copy or merge the data into the regular table. Creating a non-standard representation of the data seems like a dead-end to me.

An alternate would be to use YAML files which are more flexible and much more robust.

Comment: about the second requirement with CSV. This is the format shopify wants. This is how they store product photos if there are more than 1. Image src and the position as the following column.  Any chance on how i could approach this

Comment: The following _column_ or following _row_? The following column could meet the spec.

Comment: Yeah the column would meet the spec. The row where I am having issues. I created a new question for this. Here is the link; your help would be much appreciated
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836340/how-to-format-xml-to-csv-via-nikogori-and-csv-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Here is code you can try. I don't see a `FLDeptName` node in the XML, so I commented the lines related to that node.

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = File.read('roduct_catalog.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

all_the_things = []

doc.xpath('//Products/Product').each do |file|
  handle = file.xpath("./ItemNumber").first.text
  title = file.xpath("./Name").first.text
  description = file.xpath("./Description").first.text
  # collection = file.xpath("./FLDeptName").first.text #<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  image1 = "www.mybaseurl.com/" + file.xpath("./ImageFile").first.text
  # all_the_things << [ handle, title, description, collection,  image1]#<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  all_the_things << [handle, title, description, image1]
end


CSV.open('product_file_1.csv', 'wb') do |row|
  # row << [ 'handle', 'title', 'description','collection' 'image1'] #<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  row << ['handle', 'title', 'description', 'image1']
  all_the_things.each do |data|
    row << data
  end
end
```

Here is the output.
[image]

---

Sample XML with two images:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ProductCatalogImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Name>36-In. Homeowner Bent Single-Bit Axe Handle</Name>
      <Description>This single bit curved grip axe handle is made for 3 to 5 pound axes. A good quality replacement
        handle made of American hickory with a natural wax finish. Hardwood handles do not conduct electricity and
        American Hickory is known for its strength, elasticity and ability to absorb shock. These handles provide
        exceptional value and economy for homeowners and other occasional use applications. Each Link handle comes with
        the required wedges, rivets, or epoxy needed for proper application of the tool head.
      </Description>
      <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
      <ImageFile2>100024-2.jpg</ImageFile2>
      <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
      <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
    </Product>

    <Product>
      <Name>1-1/4-Inch Lavatory Pop Up Assembly</Name>
      <Description>Classic chrome finish with ABS plastic top &amp; body includes push rod, no overflow.</Description>
      <ImageFile>100024.jpg</ImageFile>
      <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
      <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
    </Product>

    <Product>
      <Name>30-Inch Belt-Drive Whole-House Attic Fan With Shutter</Name>
      <Description>The 30" belt drive whole house fan (5700 CFM) with automatic shutter helps cool living spaces up to
        1900 square feet. It runs on high &amp; low and a 2 speed wall switch is included. The automatic shutter is
        white. It needs 1095 square inches of open exhaust vents in attic space, with a rough opening of 34-1/4" x 29".
        You do have to cut joist when installing fan, with the motor mounted on struts above housing. The fan will be
        quieter than direct drive models. There is a 10 year limited parts warranty, 5 year limited labor warranty.
      </Description>

      <ImageFile>100073.jpg</ImageFile>
      <ItemNumber>100024</ItemNumber>
      <ModelNumber>64707</ModelNumber>
    </Product>
  </Products>
  <ProductCatalogImport/>
```

This is code to write the content in a different row:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = File.read('roduct_catalog.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

all_the_things = []

doc.xpath('//Products/Product').each do |file|
  handle = file.xpath("./ItemNumber").first.text
  title = file.xpath("./Name").first.text
  description = file.xpath("./Description").first.text
  # collection = file.xpath("./FLDeptName").first.text #<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  image1 = "www.mybaseurl.com/" + file.xpath("./ImageFile").first.text
  if file.xpath("./ImageFile2").size() > 0
    image2 = "www.mybaseurl.com/" + file.xpath("./ImageFile2").first.text
  else
    image2 = ''
  end

  # all_the_things << [ handle, title, description, collection,  image1]#<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  all_the_things << [handle, title, description, image1, image2]
end


CSV.open('product_file_1.csv', 'wb') do |row|
  # row << [ 'handle', 'title', 'description','collection' 'image1'] #<== commented because as ./FLDeptName node not present
  row << ['handle', 'title', 'description', 'image1', 'image2']
  all_the_things.each do |data|
    if data[-1] != ''
      row << data[0...-1]
      row << [data[0], '', '', '', data[-1]]
    else
      row << data
    end

  end
end
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Wow so simple. Thank you so MUCH!!! If its not too much i would love to run another one by you. There is a column I will be adding say column image2. I want to ruby to check if the column is empty and if it isn’t to create a new row with the same handle value but the value of image2. Is that possible? I can update the question above to reflect the question asked

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you don't mind post another question with the sample xml. So that we don't confuse the future readers.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "updated" tags in your text. Simply incorporate changes into the text as if it'd been there all along. SO isn't a message list or forum, it's more like an online programming Q&A reference book, and the order of changes isn't nearly as important as readability. We can see when something changed if we need to.

Comment: @supputuri I changed the question like you asked. First of all thank you for your help.  The 1st solution worked and the second solution partially. For some reason in the image2 field the base url was being printed when image2 field is empty. I fixed by adding file.xpath("./AltImageFile1").first.text.size() in the if statement. Now final question what if i had an image 3 and 4 & decided to do the same thing how would i handle it. Also if you could explain newly added code in the CSV I would forever grateful.  Thanks again for your help. –

Comment: @the Tin Man Let me know if you can help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465634/combining-two-xml-files-into-with-nokogori

Comment: It's not necessary, and not really desirable, to tell us that you changed the question. We can see what changed, when and where.